# State of the art of SAT on a quantum computer

Tags: complexity-theory

Disclaimer:  I don't understand quantum computing.

Given a CNF boolean formula $\phi$ in $n$ variables
and quantum computer with $q$ qubits, what is the
complexity of solving $\phi$ as a function of $n,q$?

I am mainly interested when $q$ is polynomial in $n$.

Can we get $2^{o(n)}$ (small Oh, [Exponential time hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis))?

I believe on a traditional computer the complexity is $C^n$
for a constant $C < 2$.

Comment: a related question on cstheory: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/36428/29288

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an open question. People who try to prove $\text{BQP} = \text{NP}$ usually use the SAT formulation, in my experience. But we don't know of any algorithm that addresses the structure of the SAT problem.

The best you can do is a naive implementation of a Grover-like amplitude dispersion, which will give you a square-root speedup. (You can read that in the linked discussion on CS stack exchange.)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to psitae's answer, in 2 recent papers by Aaronson, Chia, Lin, Wang and Zhang ([arXiv:1911.01973](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.01973)) and Buhrman, Patro and Speelman ([arXiv:1911.05686](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.05686)) the *Quantum Strong Exponential Time Hypothesis* (QSETH) was formulated. This hypothesis in fact claims that there is no $2^{o(n)}$ quantum algorithm for solving $k-\mathrm{SAT}$.